# How to create wallets using monero-wallet-rpc?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

`monero-wallet-rpc` requires to use of a pre-generated wallet to run. E.g.:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 28083 --wallet-file monerowallet --disable-rpc-login
```

Whereas I want to allow users to create wallets at runtime with the RPC. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. First make sure you start the wallet RPC with a wallet dir that exists and is writeable. Next you can make use of the methods `create_wallet`, `open_wallet` and `close_wallet`. All the methods are documented here: https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html

I don't recall if you are required to start the RPC with an existing wallet, but if you are, just create an empty wallet to use for starting up the wallet RPC with.

Comment: should I always call `close_wallet` before creating another one?

Comment: You don't need to, it is done automatically.